# Creating a simple internet chat

Tags: java, network-programming

I tried to create a simple chat via sockets and it works for LAN right now and for "localhost" too, of course, but not among different computers through the internet and thats the real point of a chat, isn't it!

```
socket = new Socket("--ip address--", 7345);
```

This line works for --ip address-- = localhost and --ip address-- = ""my local ip-address"", but with the ip address of my router, it throws a java.net.ConnectException

```
" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect "
```

I want to use my pc as server and not a real server, maybe there is the problem, but I think that there must be a solution. If that is an absurd simple question, don't doom me, because I'm a real newbie in network programming.

Comment: Your router is unlikely to have port 7345 open.

Comment: And if it was open, your router is unlikely to know to send traffic on that port to your computer.

Comment: You are most likely having a firewall problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are creating a server, you have to use server socket with the ip address of where it's running...

The server socket needs to be running on your machine of your machine's ip address.

With your router, you need to forward the connections to the port you are running on your that is hosting the server.

Then you should be able to connect from outside your local network.

Without the code for what your are doing it's hard to tell if that's the only problem  here is a simple chat server that might give you guidance.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatServer
{  private Socket          socket   = null;
   private ServerSocket    server   = null;
   private DataInputStream streamIn =  null;

   public ChatServer(int port)
   {  try
      {  
         System.out.println("Binding to port " + port + ", please wait  ...");
         server = new ServerSocket(port);  
         System.out.println("Server started: " + server);
         System.out.println("Waiting for a client ..."); 
         socket = server.accept();
         System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket);
         open();
         boolean done = false;
         while (!done)
         {  try
            {  String line = streamIn.readUTF();
               System.out.println(line);
               done = line.equals(".bye");
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {  
              done = true;
            }
         }
         close();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {  System.out.println(ioe); 
      }
  }
   public void open() throws IOException
   {  streamIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
   }
   public void close() throws IOException
  {  if (socket != null)    socket.close();
     if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
  }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  ChatServer server = null;
      if (args.length != 1)
         System.out.println("Usage: java ChatServer port");
      else
         server = new ChatServer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
   }
}
```

Comment: OP said his existing server works fine on LAN, it's when he tries to go over the internet that there's a problem.

Comment: Then the first part of my answer should cover that.  OP is trying to bind to his router which is incorrect.  My answer clearly states that port forwarding is necessary to access outside of local network.  OP should not be binding to his routers IP, it should still be his machine, and his router will forward through to the port on his machine.